# Select and Display text from a .txt file within a file chooser within Android Java

Tags: java, android

I have created a file chooser within the ListActivity, which lists and allows you to select a file within the TravelLogs directory within the internal storage of my device.

The Objective:
I am looking to display text from the .txt file I chose from my file chooser within a TextView,  from within dispText within the activity_list.xml file.

Any suggestions or resources?  I have been through every tutorial on the topic and must be misunderstanding.

Updated to the most current code as of Nov27 @1226pm pst

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView dispText;
Button buttonOpenDialog;

TextView textFolder;

String KEY_TEXTPSS = "TEXTPSS";
static final int CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID = 0;
ListView dialog_ListView;

File root;
File curFolder;

private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    buttonOpenDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.opendialog);
    buttonOpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TravelLogs");
    curFolder = root;

    dispText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_file_data);
}




public String getTextFileData(String fileName) {

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    Log.d("jason", "fileName: " + fileName );
    try {


        FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIS, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line + '\n');
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        text.append("IOException: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        Log.e("Error!", "Error occured while reading text file from Internal Storage!");

    }

    return text.toString();

}





@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    Dialog dialog = null;

    switch (id) {
        case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
            dialog = new Dialog(ListActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
            dialog.setTitle("Select Log");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            textFolder = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.folder);


            dialog_ListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);
            dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new     AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.d("jason", "fileName: " + fileName );
                    File selected = new File(fileList.get(position));
                    if(selected.isDirectory()) {
                        ListDir(selected);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, selected.toString() + " selected",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dismissDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
                        String text = getTextFileData(selected.getAbsolutePath());
                        Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, text.toString() + " line",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            break;
    }
    return dialog;

}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    switch (id) {
        case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
            ListDir(curFolder);
            break;
    }
}

void ListDir(File f) {


    curFolder = f;
    textFolder.setText(f.getPath());

    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    fileList.clear();

    for(File file : files) {
        fileList.add(file.getPath());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
    dialog_ListView.setAdapter(directoryList);
}




@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(ListActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();

}


@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    startActivity(new Intent(ListActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
    return true;
}



}
```

Comment: Well what is the problem?

Comment: `Simply looking to view the text of the selected text`. The selected text or selected file? Well can the user select a file? You should tell what happens. And what not happens. So your dialog comes up. Then what does the user see? I think no files are displayed. The fileList and  listView are empty.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, selected.toString() + " selected",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` Does this Toast() come up? If yes, what does the user see?

Comment: `Log.d("jason", "fileName: " + fileName );`. Please place as first statement in that function. Tell us what gets logged.

Comment: In the catch block add  `text.append("IOException:  " + e.getMessage() + "\n");`.

Comment: Functions like getTextFileData() are not called automatically. So i wanna see where you call them. And how. I wanna see which value you use for the fileName parameter too. You should call that function as soon as the user choosed a file.

Comment: You can remove a lot of comments. Otherwise moderators come in.

Comment: We start again: You have a function getTextFileData(). You are calling that function in function getTextFile(). You are calling it wrong. More about that later. First forget that you have a function getTextFile(). You should now call getTextFileData() from another place in your code. Please edit your post and add a line to call that function. Also add the two cide lines i asked befire.

Comment: Updated to the most recent code.  Feels very close.

Comment: I'm waiting for you to add that call.

Comment: No. I see no call to getTextFileData(). Do you?

Comment: Nonsense. I believe you have not the faintest idea of what i am asking.

Comment: `it is the only part of my code that doesn't work correctly within a whole large app.`. Sorry, but i do not believe that you wrote a big app. I do also not believe that you wrote a small app. Further i do not believe that you wrote one line of the code you posted. If you had done all that coding than you had not asked for help as you do now. What you ask is the so simple and elementary that i cannot believe that you have troubles with it or would ask. The answers you give on my questions are way beyond what would look like a normal answer.

Comment: I have been on this one problem for too long.

Anyway, I have updated the text, but it does not compile now.  Please look above if i did it right

Comment: It's time to go to bed.

Comment: Opensource development is there for everybody to learn and use within the license and I am completely compliant. Opensource community coding exists so we can all learn and pass on the knowledge as well. And after second guessing myself, I looked back to analyze my code and everything is opensource or I wrote it myself. I have written 3 apps, started out doing webview html css javascript.  You are slandering and defaming me for trying to learn greenapps. Why would you ridicule me for learning java coding in the way that most self-taught developers learn?

Comment: `The answers you give on my questions are way beyond what would look like a normal answer. `

Comment: `You should now call getTextFileData() from another place in your code. Please edit your post and add a line to call that function. `

Comment: `I'm waiting for you to add that call. ` You did not manige to add that call. A basic thing you would know after an your fiirst hour of programming. Instead you reply with garbage. I like to help you but did not manage. Sorry. You were close. Just adding that line and then change three or four code lines a bit. Thats all. So close.

Comment: I am going through a udacity course on the topic right now. But if you know the answer, please show me..

Comment: Well you should call that function -which gets the contents of a text file- as soon as you know which file the user choosed. You are already doing something now as soon as the user choosed a file. Please tell what you do now. And add the call right after it.

Comment: Is this right? getTextFileData(selected.toString()); 

where should i put it?

Comment: It is nearly right. And i already told you where you have to place it. And you did not tell what you are doing already now. Im disappointed.

Comment: after the toast

Comment: seems if i put a string call in a void, it wouldnt work.  this is why i am asking.    will i need to change the type to public string instead of void?

Comment: Thats ok. But yet better after dismissDialog. Please put it there. Then tell what happens and what gets logged. You have already `public String getTextFileData(String fileName) `. Throw the other away.

Comment: This is what is logged with the following code above.

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jason.v4, PID: 28606
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/emulated/0/TravelLogs/2017-11-17_16-42-15PM.txt contains a path separator
at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2865)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:1332)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:190)
at com.jason.v4.ListActivity.getTextFileData(ListActivity.java:80)
at com.jason.v4.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:137)

Comment: Yes, yes. Ok. That was to be expected. Dont worry. We will solve that soon.  Now first change `getTextFileData(selected.toString());` to `String text = getTextFileData(selected.getAbsolutePath());`.

Comment: And after that line add another Toast to display `text` to the user.

Comment: Please tell what gets logged by `Log.d("jason", "fileName: " + fileName );`.

Comment: It has not logged Log.d.  Where would I find it?

I have updated the code above, please advise if I added the Log.d in the correct line.

Comment: You added ik ok. But you should have told us what was displayed by the second toast of course. And change `text.toString()` to `text`.

Comment: That log statement is in your code. If you do not see it you are blind.

Comment: `FileInputStream fIS = getApplicationContext().openFileInput(fileName);`. Change to `FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream(fileName);`.

Comment: `It has not logged Log.d. Where would I find it? `. Where you normally find it. In the LogCat of Android Studio. The same place where you found the fatal exception description you posted.

Comment: It now works but instead of displaying the textfile data into the textView dispText, it displays in a toast and then disappears.

Here is the only log as i click the file name

E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: Well gratulations! You finaly managed. And indeed the content of the file displays in a toast. As there is code to do so. And toasts are very short lived. And the content does not display in a text view. Of course not. There is no code that puts that text in a text view isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileInputStream fIS = getApplicationContext().openFileInput(fileName);
```

Change to

```
FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream(fileName);
```

Further i consider this post solved.

For further detail questions make another post to solve them.

Comment: Thanks again for all of the help